# display images based on combo box item selection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have 3 comboboxes like below on difference location with 3 images under every combo box.

```
<ComboBox Name="Category1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="40,20,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="120"
        Loaded="Category1_Loaded"
        SelectionChanged="Category1_SelectionChanged"/>
        <Image Width="120" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,40,0,0" Name="CB1" Source="C:\Users\Image1.png" />

        <ComboBox Name="Category2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="40,20,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="120"
        Loaded="Category2_Loaded"
        SelectionChanged="Category2_SelectionChanged"/>
        <Image Width="120" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,40,0,0" Name="CB2" Source="C:\Users\Image2.png" />

        <ComboBox Name="Category3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="40,20,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="120"
        Loaded="Category3_Loaded"
        SelectionChanged="Category3_SelectionChanged"/>
        <Image Width="120" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,40,0,0" Name="CB3" Source="C:\Users\Image3.png" />
```

and .cs code

```
 private void Category1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ... A List.
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            data.Add("Category1_1");
            data.Add("Category1_2");
            // ... Get the ComboBox reference.
            var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
            // ... Assign the ItemsSource to the List.
            comboBox.ItemsSource = data;
            // ... Make the first item selected.
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

private void Category2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ... A List.
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            data.Add("Category2_1");
            data.Add("Category2_2");
            // ... Get the ComboBox reference.
            var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
            // ... Assign the ItemsSource to the List.
            comboBox.ItemsSource = data;
            // ... Make the first item selected.
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
private void Category3_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ... A List.
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            data.Add("Category3_1");
            data.Add("Category3_2");
            // ... Get the ComboBox reference.
            var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
            // ... Assign the ItemsSource to the List.
            comboBox.ItemsSource = data;
            // ... Make the first item selected.
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

Now 3 combo boxes and images like below
[image]

> I want to change or display a particular image based on dropdown
>   selection. for example If I select dropdown value `Category1_1` it
>   should show me image `c:\users\Category1_1.PNG`

Comment: What code do you have in the SelectionChanged event of the combos?

Comment: I don't have any for now as I want to do it dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may bind the Image's `Source` property directly to the `SelectedItem` of the corresponding ComboBox with a Binding Converter that converts the category string to a BitmapImage:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" .../>
<Image Source="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox1,
                        Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
```

The converter would look like this:

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            var path = string.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}.png", value);
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null; // or some default image
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

---

As a note, you could easily create the ComboBox item list in XAML like this:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" SelectedIndex="0" ...>
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <sys:String>Category1_1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Category1_2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Category1_3</sys:String>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to test it now, but taking some bit of examples from MSDN your selected changed event for the combobox Category1 should be something like this

```
    private void Category1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

        // Check if you have something selected (this happens sometime)
        if(comboBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            // Take the text of the combo and build the path to the file
            string fileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\users", comboBox.Text + ".png"); 

            // Again, check if we really have that file available
            if(File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                // Build a BitmapImage from the file
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.UriSource = new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative);
                bi.EndInit();

                // Set the Image for this combo. Not sure if the Stretch part is needed
                CB1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                CB1.Source = bi3;
            } 
        }
    }
```

The reference from MSDN are

[Image.Source property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.110).aspx)
[ComboBox.Text Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also, I am not sure if reading Text property works as expected (Possible problems caused by the ComboBox IsEditable property). In any case you could use SelectedItem.ToString()

If you make this work for the combo Category1 then this could easily refactored to be a generic method for all three combos passing the combo originating the event and the Image to update